# How to interpret band structures

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

I'm currently taking a Solid State Physics class, and is currently reading about the quantum mechanical description of solids.

I then came across the following figure:

[image: Band structure for Al]

It's supposed to be the band structure for aluminium. My question is basically: How do I interpret these band structures ? I can't even see why they cut of the region from $X$ to $\Gamma$ at the dotted line in the first figure, and not in the second :/ Why is the last bit of $X$ to $\Gamma$ that you see in figure 2, not important in figure 1 ?

I understand that, the $X$, $\Gamma$, $K$, $L$ and $W$ are points of symmetry on the brillioun zone. But what does it mean for the electron(s) ? Only that they have higher energies at some points ?

I'm just having some trouble understanding what this band structure tells me, and what I'm able to see/do with it ?

So can anyone maybe explain it, maybe even easily, what I actually have to understand when I see this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have already stated, the polyeder in the upper part of the figure is plotted in 3D k-space and visualizes the first Brillouin zone. The dotted line nicely visualizes a closed (one-dimensional) path in k-space that -- by convention -- runs through the special points you already mentioned. Now, this ***closed*** path is precisely the horizontal axis in the lower part of the figure (this is why it starts and ends with $\Gamma$) and what is plotted in this figure is the energy dispersion $E(\vec{k})$.

As stated in the answer of user D-K, this is done to capture some important features in a 2D plot because we don’t know how to conveniently draw a 4D plot on a sheet of paper ;) .

Answer (score 2):

To fully present the dispersion relation E(k) needs a 4D space, which cannot be intuitive.
Instead, we can use a 2D band diagram to show the most important features (along high-symmetry directions) of the band structure.
Another way is to give the constant-E isosurfaces, such as Fermi surface. Many such isosurfaces will give you a 3D feeling of what the band structure is like.